# Forwarding SIGTERM over ssh

Tags: ssh, signals

I want ssh to forward the SIGTERM signal to the remote command.

```
ssh root@localhost /root/print-signal.py
```

Get PID of ssh:

```
ps aux| grep print-signal
```

Kill the matching ssh process:

```
kill pid-of-ssh
```

Unfortunately only the ssh process itself gets the signal, not the remote command (`print-signal.py`). The remote command does not terminate :-(

How can I make ssh "forward" the SIGTERM signal to the remote command?

Comment: The print-signal.py script is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669030/633961

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47581495/13317

Comment: Since there seems to be no answer, I created a new question: How to work around this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419781/work-around-ssh-does-not-forward-signal

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103699/kill-process-spawned-by-ssh-when-ssh-dies

Comment: Maybe you should try to catch the signal Inside your Python script, I guess the signal is not transmitted since the script is not stopped but I can give us a hint of what's going on

Answer (score 1):

I think  you can do the following :

```
ssh root@localhost /root/print-signal.py
```

**Get PID of python file running **

ps aux| grep print-signal

Kill the matching ssh process:

```
ssh root@localhost "kill <pid>"
```

Here you are sending command to remote host .

Hope this solves your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Send via SSH this (tested on sleep process):

```
$(proc=$(pidof sleep) && kill $proc)
```