# Work around ssh does not forward signal

Tags: linux, ssh, kill

How can I work around the problem that `ssh` does not forward the `SIGTERM` signal?

I want `print-signal.py` to terminate of the `ssh root@localhost` process terminates:

```
ssh root@localhost /root/print-signal.py
```

Unfortunately only the ssh process itself gets the signal, not the remote command (`print-signal.py`). The remote command does not terminate :-(

Since openssh does not forward the `SIGTERM` to the remote command, I am searching for a work-around.

How to terminate `print-signal.py` if `ssh root@localhost` ... terminates?

This is a follow-up question to: [Forwarding SIGTERM over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377993/forwarding-sigterm-over-ssh)

Comment: It seems impossible to send over a particular signal and kill a command with that particular signal. `ssh -t server cmd` allows a clean termination of `cmd` on `server`, but this is due to `SIGHUP`. if you use `ssh server cmd`, and kill the ssh, `cmd` will become a child of `init` and will be eventually killed off by `SIGPIPE`. The only way to send `SIGTERM` to the process is possible by a secondary ssh (`ssh server "pgrep -U $USER cmd | xargs kill -SIGTERM"`). But again, this is problematic if you have multiple instances of such ssh running.

Comment: Another option would be to watch for a parent process (ppid) change in the python script and catch that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: the answer below is not for SIGTERM, but SIGINT. This is not an answer to the question due to oversight.*

The problem you are observing is due to a missing tty which should be in control of the process you try to run. If there is no tty available, ssh is unable to send the signals to the process. When you use the option `-t` to the `ssh` command, it will force pseudo-terminal allocation which makes it possible to send signals over ssh :

```
ssh -t root@localhost /root/print-signal.py
```

> **`man ssh`** `-t`   Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple `-t` options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

A very nice explanation how and why is given by [Giles on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39638).

Here you see how it works :

```
[terminal 1]% ssh server ./print_signal.py
```

On an other terminal you see then that `print_signal.py` is running on `PID=26992` under the `ssh` with `PID=26991` without a tty (`username@notty`)

```
[terminal 2]% ssh server ps -f                                                                                                                                                                                                            
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username 26991 26989  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@notty
username 26992 26991  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 python ./print_signal.py
username 27347 27345  0 17:07 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@notty
username 27348 27347  0 17:07 ?        00:00:00 ps -f
```

After killing the ssh process with kill or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the process is still active but runs now under `/sbin/init` (`PPID=1`)

```
[terminal 2]% ssh server ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username 26992     1  0 17:06 ?        00:00:00 python ./print_signal.py
username 27453 27451  0 17:08 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@notty
username 27454 27453  5 17:08 ?        00:00:00 ps -f
```

using the `-t` flag nicely kills the process on the other side:

```
[terminal 1]% ssh -t server ./print_signal.py
```

On an other terminal you see then that `print_signal.py` is running on `PID=39277` under the `ssh` with `PID=39276` bound to a tty (`username@pts/10`)

```
[terminal 2]% ssh server ps -U username -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username 39276 39274  0 17:22 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@pts/10
username 39277 39276  1 17:22 pts/10   00:00:00 python ./print_signal.py
username 39317 39314  0 17:22 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@notty
username 39318 39317  5 17:22 ?        00:00:00 ps -U username -f
```

After killing the ssh process

```
[terminal 1]% ssh -t server ./print_signal.py
My PID: 39277
^CCaught signal SIGINT (2), exiting.
Connection to server closed
```

The process is now clearly terminated on the other server

```
[terminal 2]% ssh server ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username 39768 39765  0 17:26 ?        00:00:00 sshd: username@notty
username 39769 39768  6 17:26 ?        00:00:00 ps -U username -f
```

Comment: What version of ssh are you using?

Comment: @guettli openssh-7.4

Comment: @guettli also works on `openssh-5.3` and on unix systems with `Sun_SSH_1.1.6, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f`

Comment: @guettli, did you try multiple combinations of `-t`, eg. `ssh -t -t localhost cmd`. This might be helpful, multiple combinations force the tty to exist, even if the cmd is not executed in a tty.

Comment: @guettli any luck?

Comment: The question asks about SIGTERM. ^C triggers SIGINT, not SIGTERM. There are other signals that you can trigger through a TTY, but SIGTERM isn't one of them.

Comment: @Kenster   ... Valid Point. Oversight from my side.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been having exactly this problem.  While I haven't figured out the exact cause, what happens when `ssh` is terminated is that your process is re-parented to `init`.  You can tell your process to ask for a signal when it's parent dies instead using [prctl](https://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl).

If you use [python-prctl](https://pythonhosted.org/python-prctl/), put the following early on in `/root/print-signal.py`

```
import signal
import prctl

prctl.set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works for me just fine. I had the same problem with a flask server started over ssh : the flask server nerver ends whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper which terminates if the parent process is the init process:

```
ssh root@localhost terminate-command-if-parent-is-lost print-signal.py
```

The tool `terminate-command-if-parent-is-lost` needs to do this:

Start the argv as subprocess (in this example `print-signal.py`). Then it checks every second the status of its parent pid (in Python `os.getppid()`).

If ppid is 1 (the init process), then the print-signal.py process has lost its parent. This means "ssh root@localhost ..." was terminated (or connection was closed).

Now `terminate-command-if-parent-is-lost` terminates the subprocess.

Comment: Feels too complicated. I guess there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

The shell can easily help you for such problem, if it supports some builtin variable( $! ). 
Here is a basic shell solution by replacing your command by a very long sleep.

```
ssh server '(sleep 100000 & (MID=$!; A=n; while [ "$A" != y ];do echo "i am process $$ want kill "$MID" y/n?"; read A; done; kill -TERM $MID))'
```

The script sent in the command is running on the remote host.